# why so slow when I insert row with many columns into HBase?

Tags: insert, hbase

I want to insert data into HBase from database,
but One row with many columns(more than fifty, there is only one column family).
And I have 4 region servers, but the performance of insert 
less than 10000 rows/sec.

what can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the hardware side of things (i.e. get better harddrives/servers/etc.) there are ways to optimize Put commands. I don't know how you're talking to HBase, but there are settings you can disable (like WAL) to increase performance and executing many Puts at the same time. Additionally, you should ensure you don't have a lot of row-key collisions as these create hot spots and degrade Region Server performance.

Comment: yes, I have already disabled WAL and pre-sharing rowkey. It seems better right now.